# 404s on custom sections and entries

Tags: url, sections

I have created a section called "Services" and an entry within called "seo".  When I click to view that entry in the admin area, it takes me to domain.com/services/seo, as expected, but that 404s.

Is there anything else required to use channels?

I have .htaccess in place working properly and the shipped sections ('News', and the home page) all load fine.

Comment: Under your section's settings, what's the template path set to?  Does that template exist?

Comment: Ah, do I need to create one? I assumed it would inherit a default one of some kind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to create a template, and add the path to that template to the **Entry Template** field in your "Services" section's settings.

For instance, if you create a template called `/craft/templates/services/_entry.html`, you'd use the path `services/_entry` for your section's **Entry Template** field.

With this setup, you could also add an `index.html` file to the `/craft/templates/services` folder. That template would render when the user visits the URL `domain.com/services`, enabling you to create a listing/index view for your "Services" section.

For more info, I'd suggest looking at [the excellent official docs on templating](https://craftcms.com/docs/templating-overview) in Craft.

Comment: @mikemike you should also have a look at the [documentations on routing](https://craftcms.com/docs/routing), case 3 and 5 are relevant for this setup.